# Waiting for asynchronous functions called inside for loop to finish in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, wait

I'm developing a web application where text messages are to be sent to several users once the form is submitted. I've created a for loop that loops through all numbers and sends the messages using async waterfall. But the problem is since the function calls inside the for loop are asynchronous, the for loop finishes and the `res.end()` is called. Therefore the, all the `res.write();` functions inside the doesn't since the response is already closed. How can I wait till all the callbacks from the functions inside the for loop are executed to end the response.

```
res.write("Delivery note issued successfully")
res.write("Sending text messages....")

let api = '000000000000'

for(let i = 0; i < textMessageNumbers.length; i++) {
    res.write("Sending to " + textMessageNumbers[i])
    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            request('https://api_link?destination=' + textMessageNumbers[i] + '&q=' + api + '&message=' + textMessage, { json: true }, callback)
        }
    ], function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            res.write("Error occurred while sending text message to " + textMessageNumbers[i])
        }

        if(data[0].body == 0) {
            res.write("Text message sent successfully to <b>" + textMessageNumbers[i] + "</b>")
        } else {
            res.write("Couldn't send message to <b>" + textMessageNumbers[i] + "</b>")
        }
    })
}

res.write("Delivery Note Successfull")
res.end()
```

Comment: Use `Promise.all` to wait for all promises to resolve and end the request in a `then` or with async/await

Comment: How about `async.each` as you are already using `async`